# Getting 401 Unauthorized error while requasting GitHub API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good evening. My task is to create a website with react that will list through github users. I was following this instruction: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/users#get-a-user (for JS). My credentials:

```
async function searchUsers() {
  try {
    const octokit = new Octokit({
      auth: 'ghp_MY_PERSONAL_TOKEN',
      acceptstring: 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'
    })
    const response = await octokit.request(`GET /users/${name}`, {
      username: 'maria98kgm'
    });

    setUsers(response.data);
    setLoading(false);
    searchRepos();
    } 
    catch(e) {
      setLoading(false);
      setUsers('notFound');
      console.error('no such a user');
   }
}
```

Whenever i use it too long or push changes to github, it stops working and gives me `401 Unauthorized` error:
[image]

I cannot solve it for two days already, please help.

Comment: This seems like it would only throw this error if your token was invalid or doesn't have access to whatever you're requesting, but in this case, it's likely that you have an invalid token. I'd just go ahead and generate a new one and try with that.

Comment: I tried it, but its still not working

Comment: Are you using auto expire tokens?  These are only good for 8 hours and must be refreshed using a separate refresh token which lasts 6 months. See: [Expiring user access tokens](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/refreshing-user-to-server-access-tokens)

Comment: no, im using personal access tokens: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: did you check the permissions of the token ?

Comment: consol says that access denied because im not authorized

Comment: It set to repo. I tried to change it to none but that didnt work either. May this error appear if i didn specify user_agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any authentication for that endpoint. Here's a working example:

- [Octokit.js docs](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.js#octokit-api-client)
- [GitHub REST API docs for getting a user](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/users#get-a-user)

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
button, input[type="text"] { font-size: 1rem; padding: 0.2rem; }
pre { font-family: monospace; font-size: 1rem; }
.vertical { display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-start; gap: 0.5rem; }
```

```html
<!-- Babel seemed to have trouble with this, so I'm putting it on window -->
<script type="module">
  import {Octokit} from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/octokit@1.7.1';
  window.Octokit = Octokit;
</script>

<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.18.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

// import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
// import {useState} from 'react';
// import {Octokit} from 'octokit';

// This Stack Overflow snippet demo uses UMD modules instead of the commented import statments above
const {useState} = React;

const octokit = new Octokit();

function App () {
  const [user, setUser] = useState('maria98kgm');
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(undefined);
  const [error, setError] = useState(undefined);

  const updateUserData = async () => {
    try {
      const username = user.trim();
      const response = await octokit.request(`GET /users/${username}`);
      setUserData(response.data);
      setError(undefined);
    }
    catch (ex) {
      if (ex instanceof Error) setError(ex);
      else console.error(ex);
    }
  };

  const displayString = error
    ? error.toString()
    : userData
      ? JSON.stringify(userData, null, 2)
      : 'No data yet';

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="vertical">
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={ev => setUser(ev.target.value)}
          value={user}
        />
        <button onClick={updateUserData}>Update user data</button>
      </div>
      <pre><code>{displayString}</code></pre>
    </div>
  );
}

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
reactRoot.render(<App />);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation of the error.

The 404 status code means your authentication data are not the good ones.

### How to solve it.

- First, check your GitHub personal token is ok (i am guessing it is)
- Second, do the following : https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/identifying-and-authorizing-users-for-github-apps